# No module named pandas in zeppelin pyspark

Tags: pandas, pyspark, apache-zeppelin

I am using spark interpreter in zeppelin. I am able to import other packages but not pandas. When I run

```
%pyspark
import pandas as pd
```

it shows

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/zeppelin_pyspark-4427359591293078034.py", line 367, in <module>
    raise Exception(traceback.format_exc())
Exception: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/zeppelin_pyspark-4427359591293078034.py", line 360, in <module>
    exec(code, _zcUserQueryNameSpace)
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pandas
```

I tried configuring the zeppelin-env.sh by `export PYSPARK_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python`. Please help me.

Comment: pandas installed?

Comment: Pandas is installed.Iam able to import in jupyter notebook

Comment: May be it's not using the same python. check `sys.path` if it's the same. Try to configure it `zeppelin.pyspark.python` in Zeppelin with the same one used in pyspark

Comment: It is using python2.7 only. I set `zeppelin.pyspark.python` with python